# Boost asio bind allocating more memory than it should be?

Tags: c++, memory, boost

I was going through the boost asio tutorial trying to learn how to use their networking library. I implemented the example daytime client/server which is [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime2.html) (this is only the server). When running both the client and server I get *can't allocate region* of size `mach_vm_map(size=7597121102135848960)`.

I have no idea why this is happening.

server:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

std::string make_daytime_string() {
  using namespace std;
  time_t now = time(NULL);
  return ctime(&now);
}

int main() {
  try {
    boost::asio::io_service io;
    tcp::acceptor acceptor(io);
    tcp::endpoint endpoint(tcp::v4(), 13);
    acceptor.open(endpoint.protocol());
    acceptor.set_option(tcp::acceptor::reuse_address(true));
    acceptor.bind(endpoint); // throwing error here
    acceptor.listen();
    for(;;) {
        tcp::socket socket(io);
        acceptor.accept(socket);
        std::string message = make_daytime_string();

        boost::system::error_code ignore_error;
        boost::asio::write(socket, boost::asio::buffer(message), ignore_error);
    }

  }
  catch(std::exception& e) {
    std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

client:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
   try {
      if(argc != 2) {
        std::cerr << "Usage: client <host>" << std::endl;
        return 1;
      }
      boost::asio::io_service io_service;
      tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
      tcp::resolver::query query(argv[1], "daytime");
      tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator =     resolver.resolve(query);
      tcp::socket socket(io_service);
      boost::asio::connect(socket, endpoint_iterator); // error here
      for(;;) {
        boost::array<char, 128> buf;
        boost::system::error_code error;
        size_t len = socket.read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buf), error);
        if(error == boost::asio::error::eof) 
            break;
        else if(error)
            throw boost::system::system_error(error);

        std::cout.write(buf.data(), len);
      }
  }
  catch(std::exception& e) {
    std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The error is basically the same for both with only a different size:

error:

```
sserver(14988,0x7fffdc3283c0) malloc: ***    mach_vm_map(size=7597121102135848960) failed (error code=3)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
sserver(14988,0x7fffdc3283c0) malloc: 
*** error for object    0x7373696d72655022: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
[1]    14988 abort      ./sserver
```

I anyone know how to fix this I would greatly appreciate it. I should note that I am compiling with g++ 6.1.0 and boost 1.60.02.

Comment: This sounds like straight up [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because the code shown has no such problems (assuming your `/etc/services` is not a malicious file)

Comment: Can you post the complete back trace ?